# Ruby on Rails CRUD and User authentication and authorization module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

hope you all doing well.

my question is on ruby technology, we are developing an web based application using rails framework and ruby. I need to know how the routing works (routes.rb), can some one send me a link of sample CRUD application which I can use in my project.

I need also User authentication and authorization framework using ruby which is readily available.

very urgent,
many many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick way of creating a Rails CRUD application with user authentication and authorization, please see the [Bullet on Rails](http://rubyforge.org/projects/bulletonrails/) project. Bullet on Rails is a project I created a *while ago* to help me quick start creating CRUD apps with authorization included and AJAX crud.

Since you seem to be new to Rails, I also recommend that you read the documentation suggested by weppos.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, you are asking how Ruby on Rails works and how to getting started.
I encourage you to start from the official documentation, including the [Wiki site](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/) and [Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/).

You can find information about Rails routing [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Routing.html). More answers about Rails Authentication and Authorization [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rails+authentication) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rails+authorization).